# 2 quick (1 long) and 3 short beeps

Tags: boot, memory, display, vga

So my "server" PC has finally started acting odd. I won't show anything on my monitor and apparently won't startup enough for me to login remotely.

When I turn it on I'm greeted with 2 quick beeps (I've read that means 1 long) and 3 short beeps. I've also read that this could be a VGA problem or a RAM problem.

If it's a VGA issue, shouldn't it still boot up?

MOBO specs:
ASUS A8N SLI-Deluxe
[link](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/AMD_Socket_939/A8NSLI_Deluxe/)

**EDIT**

The two quick beeps are very quick. "Beep Beep" and then "Beeeep" "Beeeep" "Beeeep" ... a long might translate to "Beeeeeeeep" :P

I've reseated the Video Card.

Comment: what's the difference between a quick beep and a short beep?

Comment: if the problem is the video card then that could stop it from starting up.  Try reseating the video card.

Comment: I've added edits above.

Comment: BIOS Beep Codes  http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm    not sure where yours fit! maybe somebody knows?  By the way, what make is your BIOS?

Comment: The BIOS should be in the specs at the link I posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like video failure, and it could be as simple as making sure the card is seated correctly - it is very easy to put them it at an angle and while they "feel" like they are in properly, they are not.

The minimum for a PC to boot are memory, cpu and video - so no you shouldn't expect it to boot without a video card.  Having said that, I have heard some motherboards will permit it (or rather, bioses), but it would be unusual.  It is possible that in the absense of a video card, these PCs will boot, but not with a failed card - ie it is detected as present but non-functional, so it does pass POST.

Do you have a spare card you can test with?

Comment: Can't say that I do, but if that's the case... there's my problem.

Comment: You could try taking it out altogether - if it boots (if you can work out that it has booted) you'll at least confirm the card as the issue.  If it doesn't then you'll have no more to go on than now.

Comment: You could also boot without video, since it is not needed for the actual booting. It makes it harder to debug though because on most home systems you would not be able to log in until you can SSH, X, VNC, remote desktop or similar.

Comment: @Hennes Yeah, thats what I was suggesting with "take it out all together" - if you can ping the box, then at least that is some confirmation.